# Java EE Eclipse Servlet Tomcat 7 error: The servlets named [...] are both mapped to the url-pattern [...] which is not permitted

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I just started using Eclipse Servlet and I get this error when trying to run a dynamic web project on server:

```
Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:couchfriendslsrs' did not find a matching property.
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.67
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server built:          Dec 7 2015 13:07:11 UTC
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server number:         7.0.67.0
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Version:            6.3
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Architecture:          amd64
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_71\jre
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_71-b15
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Programming Files\EclipseJEE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.67-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.67
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Programming Files\EclipseJEE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.67-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.67
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Programming Files\EclipseJEE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.67-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.67\endorsed
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_71\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_71/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_71/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_71/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\s142966\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\s142966\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\eclipse-jee-kepler-R-win32-x86_64;;.
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 479 ms
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.67
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/couchfriendslsrs]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1122)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/couchfriendslsrs]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [action_edit_profile] and [ro.lsrs.couchfriends.controllers.ActionEditProfile] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/action_edit_profile] which is not permitted
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:293)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2443)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2079)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2072)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2072)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2072)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2072)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1304)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5479)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more

    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1122)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1130)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more

    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1130)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 11 more

    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
    INFO: Stopping service Catalina
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Jan 22, 2016 7:16:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

Information:

- Running project and server on **jdk1.8.0_71**.
- C:\PathToWorkspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps shows project name.
- Regarding the url error: `The servlets named [action_edit_profile] and [ro.lsrs.couchfriends.controllers.ActionEditProfile] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/action_edit_profile] which is not permitted`, the web.xml file is thus set (example for servlet given in error):

  ```
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>action_edit_profile</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>ro.lsrs.couchfriends.controllers.ActionEditProfile</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>action_edit_profile</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/action_edit_profile</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```

  **EDIT**: Regarding possible duplication of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373077/tomcat-7-severe-a-child-container-failed-during-start) question, it is not the same problem. My problem is of url conflicts (mapping being set both in xml and java class). Rather, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714706/the-servlets-named-create-subscription-and-servlet-create-are-both-mapped-to) question helped me solve the problem.

Comment: Look at the "Caused by:" lines. See the one mentioning URI patterns?

Comment: Thanks @nitind, that was indeed the issue. Next time I'll know to better spot the error from console. A simmilar issue has already been solved as mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HttpServletRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556201/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-httpservletrequest)

Try this.

Is tomcat starting without your application deployed?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as mentioned in comments, the problem lay in the servlets being mapped in the same url-pattern. I had to comment multiple `<servlet-mapping>` blocks in web.xml for the server to run.

This issue is also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714706/the-servlets-named-create-subscription-and-servlet-create-are-both-mapped-to) where answerer explains that mapping both in web.xml and in java class will cause this error.